# Как сделать проверку на пустое поле в php чтобы запустить другой код?

Tags: php, sms

```
   <?php
  if (isset ($_POST['but']) ) {


      require_once 'sms.ru.php';
      $smsru = new SMSRU('C3A6B841-6B90-4FD6-4ED5-B4FFB841F914'); // Ваш уникальный программный ключ, который можно получить на главной странице
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $num = $_POST['num'];
      $text = $_POST['text'];

      $data = new stdClass();
      $data->to = '89065906733';
      $data->text = $name . "-" . $num . "-" . $text; // Текст сообщения

      $sms = $smsru->send_one($data);// Отправка сообщения и возврат данных в переменную


      if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
          echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ";

          echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
      } else {
          echo "Сообщение не отправлено. ";
          echo "Код ошибки: $sms->status_code. ";
          echo "Текст ошибки: $sms->status_text.";
          echo $form;
      }
  }
```

отправляется смс даже когда пустое поле

Comment: перед отправкой прставьте условие if(!empty($text)){ код отправки  } else { обратный редирект с сообщением что пустое поле}

Comment: а как записать чтобы все переменные проверялись и кнопка тоже? в одном if потомучто если поставить условие перед отправкой самой то будет ошибка

Comment: Показал на примере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте все данные которые прилетают с формы:

```
 <?php
  if (isset ($_POST['but']) ) {
     require_once 'sms.ru.php';
      $smsru = new SMSRU('C3A6B841-6B90-4FD6-4ED5-B4FFB841F914'); // Ваш уникальный программный ключ, который можно получить на главной странице
      $name = trim($_POST['name']);
      $num = trim($_POST['num']);
      $text = trim($_POST['text']);

      if(empty($name)){
           echo "Поле NAME пусто. "; 
          /*Выход или редирект*/
      }

          if(empty($num)){
           echo "Поле NUM  пусто. "; 
          /*Выход или редирект*/
      }

          if(empty($text)){
           echo "Поле TEXT  пусто. "; 
          /*Выход или редирект*/
      }



      if(!empty($name) && !empty($num) && !empty($text) ){

      $data = new stdClass();
      $data->to = '89065906733';
      $data->text = $name . "-" . $num . "-" . $text; // Текст сообщения

      $sms = $smsru->send_one($data);// Отправка сообщения и возврат данных в переменную


      if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
          echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ";

          echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
      } else {
          echo "Сообщение не отправлено. ";
          echo "Код ошибки: $sms->status_code. ";
          echo "Текст ошибки: $sms->status_text.";
          echo $form;
      }
  }

  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое но почемуто у меня теперь код html не хочет заводится что должно быть в самом конце?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in K:\xampp1\htdocs\Новая папка\index.php on line 169 последняя строка

Comment: Возможно при копировании кода вы упустили закрывающую скобку, проверьте ещё раз код

Comment: И в правду я дурачок пропустил и ещё очень важный вопрос сюда можно почему при обновлении страницы ещё раз смс отправляется это всегда так было

Comment: Это от того что вы всё делаете в одном файле (форма отправки и код), Вам надо, либо разделить логику формы от отправки смс(установить в разных файлах) , или же просто после отправки смс сделать редирект на другую страницу, чтобы данные из POST удалились

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($someVariable)) {
   //:TODO
}
```

Comment: думаю пустое поле сообщения это $_POST['text'], а $_POST['but'] всегда есть